# Thumbnails of text files

Tags: cocoa, text-files, preview

I am using a NSCollectionView to present files on the user's filesystem. The NSCollectionViewItem has two outlets, fileName and fileIcon.

While presenting a "preview" of pdfs and images is trivial, how would I get a representation of a text file (.txt, .rtf, .md)?

Much like the thumbnail representation in Finder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this awesome category by Matt G:

http://mattgemmell.com/how-to-get-a-quick-look-preview-as-an-nsimage/

Works perfectly!!!